# Extract the Frequency from the Index of the Bin in 2D DFT

Tags: image-processing, frequency-spectrum, dft, frequency-domain

How can I find the distance from DC term (center) to the peak point of the frequency in the image Fourier transform?

In the figure below, we know that the distance of the peak point goes to the edge of the high frequency file. But we don't know how far away it is.(shown in red)
[image]

For example, if the peak point is 3 pixels away from the center, is the frequency 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The units of the grid are according to the sampling frequency of the data and the number of bins.

So if the peak is 3 pixels apart on the horizontal, it means its horizontal frequency is $ 3 \frac{{F}_{s}}{{N}_{H}} $ where $ {F}_{s} $ is the sampling frequency and $ {N}_{H} $ is the number of the horizontal pixels (Width of the image).